# How stops webdev.webserver.exe

Tags: process, webdev.webserver

how can stops WebDev.WebServer.exe process without kill it??

I can do this:

taskkill /F /IM WebDev.WebServer.exe -works on Windows XP- but another solution without kill the proccess ???

Comment: Your taskkill command works on window server 2003 either. 
I succeeded to stop all WebDev.WebServer.exe by the single command after launch several ones for test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stopping a process *is* killing it.

Why do you need to "stop" the process without killing it? What do you mean by "stopping" the process?

You can use [this tool](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/pausep.aspx) to pause and resume processes.

Comment: I don't know if stop procdss WebDev.WebServer.exe is the same that kill it. Is the same stop&kill actions for the memory, appdomain, threads, ... ? Does the results of stop-kills are sames ? thanks.

Comment: I just don't understand what you mean by "stop" a process. How do you "stop" any other process?

Answer (score 3):

Yeap, you are right, it will kill all process & ASP.NET service
The problem, actually, is how to kill WebDev.WebServer40.EXE, which was run with specified port.
f.e. I have:
WebDev.WebServer40.exe /port:10254 /path:"D:...\Web1"
WebDev.WebServer40.exe /port:10512 /path:"D:...\Web2"

and taskkill /F /IM WebDev.WebServer40.exe
will close all my sites, when I want only one of them

p.s. The Author means stop process == kill process, don't mind

Answer (score 0):

Webdev.WebServer.exe is the development web server used by Visual Studio to allow quick debugging of ASP.NET applications.

Visual studio will stop it for you when it is not needed. What exact problem are you having that you want to stop it explicitly?

Comment: I have web application using the same port for any execution. For testings issues I need starts WebDev, open page, test, and stop it when I finalize testing. thanks.